# spring-cloud-config match resources but doesn't return the config to the client

Tags: spring

Spring cloud server (version 2.2.0.RELEASE) seems to match the approppriate resources (In the logs, the relevant documents are loaded from yml), but does not return the content of this configuration to the client. I injected a similar query with Postman and the response payload is the following :

**Response payload from the config server**

```
{
    "name": "core-application",
    "profiles": [
        "user,local,dev,quick"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": []
}
```

**Related logs of the config server (with --debug option) :**

```
2022-01-20 09:01:49.328 [nio-8090-exec-1] INFO  cat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-20 09:01:49.329 [nio-8090-exec-1] INFO  et.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-20 09:01:49.329 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG et.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2022-01-20 09:01:49.340 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG et.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2022-01-20 09:01:49.340 [nio-8090-exec-1] INFO  et.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 11 ms
2022-01-20 09:01:49.353 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG et.DispatcherServlet - GET "/core-application/user,local,dev,quick", parameters={}
2022-01-20 09:01:49.360 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG appingHandlerMapping - Mapped to org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController#defaultLabel(String, String)
2022-01-20 09:01:49.743 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Loading from YAML: URL [file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application.yml]
2022-01-20 09:01:49.758 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Merging document (no matchers set): {NETWORK_SQL_SUFFIX=_${NETWORK}}
2022-01-20 09:01:49.758 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Loaded 1 document from YAML resource: URL [file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application.yml]
2022-01-20 09:01:49.819 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Loading from YAML: URL [file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application-dev.yml]
2022-01-20 09:01:49.820 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Merging document (no matchers set): {configuration.profiles.default=dev}
2022-01-20 09:01:49.820 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Loaded 1 document from YAML resource: URL [file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application-dev.yml]
2022-01-20 09:01:49.852 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Loading from YAML: URL [file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application-quick.yml]
2022-01-20 09:01:49.853 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Merging document (no matchers set): {core.cache.loader={operators.exclude=, interfaces.exclude=GTFS,GTFSRT,GTFSRT_DISRUPTIONS,STIB_DISRUPTIONS,STIB_SCHEDULES_RT}}
2022-01-20 09:01:49.853 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ginTrackedYamlLoader - Loaded 1 document from YAML resource: URL [file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application-quick.yml]
2022-01-20 09:01:49.878 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG ot.SpringApplication - Loading source class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
2022-01-20 09:01:49.881 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG eApplicationListener - Activated activeProfiles user,local,dev,quick
2022-01-20 09:01:49.881 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG eApplicationListener - Loaded config file 'file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application.yml' (file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application.yml)
2022-01-20 09:01:49.882 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG eApplicationListener - Loaded config file 'file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application-dev.yml' (file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application-dev.yml) for profile dev
2022-01-20 09:01:49.882 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG eApplicationListener - Loaded config file 'file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application-quick.yml' (file:C:/Users/Edouard/sources/instantconfig/applications/core-application/core-application-quick.yml) for profile quick
2022-01-20 09:01:49.903 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG eportLoggingListener - 


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

    None


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None



2022-01-20 09:01:49.965 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG eBodyMethodProcessor - Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2022-01-20 09:01:49.968 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG eBodyMethodProcessor - Writing [Environment [name=core-application, profiles=[user,local,dev,quick], label=null, propertySources=[], (truncated)...]
2022-01-20 09:01:49.994 [nio-8090-exec-1] DEBUG et.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
```

Any idea why the content of the config is not returned to the client ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason :

The `LOCAL_GIT_REPOSITORY` environment variable, in the config server application must be defined with “regular” slashs (“/”), and I was using a windows path with backslashs (“\”).

The tricky part is that spring cloud config server handles partially the windows path (As shown in the debug logs, the .yml files are found and loaded correctly). The failure occurs almost at the end of the process, in the `clean()` function of `NativeEnvironmentRepository` class : Before sending the response to the config client, this function compares the location of the yml files to correct "patterns path", and this is where windows path are not handled correctly. (Locations are computed and mixes the two kinds of slashs : `C:\Users\Edouard\myconfig/myapp/`)

Maybe it would be a good idea that spring cloud config throw a proper error, or handles it properly.